# sidebar being displayd behind navbar

Tags: html, css

In my recent project, I have a view with this html code:

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li><a th:href="@{/}" class="title">Loja</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#" class="user">username</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <main>
      <aside>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside>

      <article>
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
```

and this css stylesheet for the sidebar (tag aside):

```
aside li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
aside li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

aside li.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/ch6gtj3p/5/

when I open this page in the browser, the top of the sidebar is hidden behind the navbar, Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: You don't share the correct CSS. In the fiddle, `header` is position absolute. That's your problem. You need to add the padding or the margin with the value of the height of your header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the `position:absolute` from your header and added

```
header:after{
  visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
```

This gives you the same effect with the header. Because you have 2 floating items you should be using a clear on the header to see the background colour rather than a `position: absolute`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch6gtj3p/6/)

The problem with using a `margin-top` fix is you will need to go back and adjust it if the height changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-top to main label in css.

```
main { 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding margin-top which will push your list down

```
aside ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
margin-top:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this in your css :

```
aside {
    margin-top: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **margin-top** in you **main tag** and it works fine.

```
main{
 margin-top:50px; 
}
```